# Is it possible to extend an existing TypeConverter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have made a control in silverlight that has a `SolidColorBrush` property. In XAML, you can set this to be preexisting Colors such as Black, Yellow, White, etc. I assume there is a `TypeConverter` that takes the string "Black" and converts it to a Color object and creates a new `SolidColorBrush` based on this object. I want this functionality to remain, but with the added capability to also accept hex strings to set the color. I would need a `TypeConverter` for this, correct? Is there a way I can extend from the current one so that I can still pass in color names?

Comment: That TypeConverter already accepts hex string like `#FF1F2F3F`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush(v=vs.95).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAML already accepts hex.  Eg:

```
Background="#FF9D661C"
```

Having the VS Properties pane open while on a XAML element helps indicate possibilities thats aren't necessarily obvious via intelisence (Eg setting Background as hex or a gradiant brush).

Comment: It should be as easy as writing `Color="#FFFFFF"`

Answer (score 1):

As @Ricibob said, the existing converter alreadys works how you want it to. In addition, it looks like all of the built in TypeConverters are sealed, so you can't inherit from them (although there's nothing keeping you from using composition to solve the problem).